# How do I display an image on the browser using Java?

Tags: java, html, json, spring, rest

I have a web service which returns a `BufferedImage` value, but I am unable to display the image in my browser, knowing that I have already converted it from `byte[]` to `BufferedImage`.

I receive a result like following.

This is how I convert the `byte[]` data (I can see the data in `byte[]`):

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> result =  new RestTemplate(messageConverters).exchange(new URI(url), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,  byte[].class );
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBody()));
    return img;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get something like this:

```
{  
   "accelerationPriority":0.5,
   "colorModel":{  
      "transparency":3,
      "numComponents":4,
      "numColorComponents":3,
      "colorSpace":{  
         "type":5,
         "numComponents":3,
         "profile":{  
            "mediaWhitePoint":[  
               0.9504547,
               1.0,
               1.0890503
            ],
            "matrix":[  
               [  
                  0.43606567,
                  0.3851471,
                  0.1430664
               ],
               [  
                  0.2224884,
                  0.71687317,
                  0.06060791
               ],
               [  
                  0.013916016,
                  0.097076416,
                  0.71409607
               ]
            ],
            "data":"AAAMSGxjbXMCEAAAbW50clJHQiBYWVogB84AAgAJAAYAMQAAYWNzcE1TRlQAAAAASUVDIHNSR0IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPbWAAEAAAAA0y1sY21zAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARY3BydAAAAVAAAAAzZGVzYwAAAYQAAABsd3RwdAAAAfAAAAAUYmtwdAAAAgQAAAAUclhZWgAAAhgAAAAUZ1hZWgAAAiwAAAAUYlhZWgAAAkAAAAAUZG1uZAAAAlQAAABwZG1kZAAAAsQAAACIdnVlZAAAA0wAAACGdmlldwAAA9Q...
```

Comment: You can't expect ImageIO to get the image out of the JSON response. It knows nothing about that. You need to parse the JSON, get the data, base64 decode it, and pass the raw image data to ImageIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the first `byte[]` you already have from the rest template is the full in memory representation of the source image. If this is the case, why involve a `BufferedImage` whatsoever? Can't you just return the byte[] directly from your controller and be sure to set an appropriate mime type in the http response header.

```
 @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage() {
        final ResponseEntity<byte[]> result =  new RestTemplate(messageConverters).exchange(new URI(url), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,  byte[].class );
        return ResponseEntity.status(OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                .body(result.getBody());
    }
```

On a separate note, if you are just proxying the image via your service back to the client there might be better solutions - such as spring cloud zuul or having the client directly access the resource. Might help to know a little about the image that you are fetching in terms of your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. By the way the image that I get is a PNG image but your solution works with JPG and PNG image. I will use this image in my Angular 4 application, should I convert it to base64 or not.

Comment: I see no reason to convert to base 64 given the details I know. Using an appropriate content-type header and returning the bytes should be sufficient.